# Bigquery LegacySQL invalid snapshot in time using special decorator @0

Tags: google-bigquery, decorator, legacy-sql

I'm running bigquery legacy sql and using the special decorator @0 it gives an error on any table:

> Invalid snapshot time 1570001838355 for table
>   upbeat-stratum-242175:my_dataset.my_data. Cannot read before
>   1570001838359

Running this again will only change with current timestamp but always shows a difference in the timestamps from the error of ~4 seconds.

Also this is happening regardless the table I run it against.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/table-decorators

Comment: It would be easier to get help if you create an issue tracker https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0

Comment: I did that. Thanks.

Comment: Here's the issue, for anyone having the same issue. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142342267

Answer (score 1):

@0 seems broken right now. Could you use @-604700000 instead?

The calculation is 3600000 * 24 * 7 = 604800000 and cut a little from the end.

It allows you to time travel back to 7 days ago, which is practically the same as @0 (when it works).

Comment: not working either. Replied to the issuetracker also.